# Redirect back to my site from third party payment system

Tags: spring-security

I provide a redirect url for a payment site. After payment is completed the payment site creates form with a submit button to bring user back to my site:

```
<form action="http://my.site.foo/payment/ok">....</form>
```

When I use **http** protocol everything works fine, but the payment site notifies user that her data will be sent unencrypted. Thus I decided to provide **https** link: `https://my.site.foo:8080/payment/ok`.
In my spring-security.xml I put

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/payment/ok" requires-channel="https" />
```

But when I submit the form on a payment site I get 403 status.
So my question is: How to configure spring for this particular situation and provide access to `https://my.site.foo:8080/payment/ok` from payment site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running over *HTTP* or *HTTPS* **isn't a Spring specific configuration**, but rather a config at the web server/application server level.

You will need set you Tomcat/Jetty to serve your application over *HTTPS* and of course that the page you redirect to is actually accessible. 
You will of course also need to buy a certificate.

Here are the instructions to set up [your Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) or [Jetty](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL) servers.

Hope it helps.